# cordova/ionic socialsharing error on Whatsapp only for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, whatsapp

ever since the last whatsapp update to version 2.16.2 on IOS i get this error when i try to share something and press on the recipient - "this item cannot be shared. please select a different item", it worked fine before!

[thats the error i get on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDwJF.png)

i'm using a plugin called "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.12 "SocialSharing"",
the output on xcode is:

"SocialSharing app selected: net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension
plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated"

i saw a few native solutions here and could not implement it on my app.

help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not providing the "Subject" attribute in the function call.

```
$cordovaSocialSharing
.share(message, image, link)
```

and not

```
.share(message, subject, image, link)
```

Comment: I tried in both ways. Sharing works fine on other platforms other than whatsapp. Do we require special permissions for sharing on whatsapp?

Comment: @Abhay Can you share both image and text at a time?

Comment: I guess we can.

Answer (score 1):

For that working correctly you must complete all fields:

window.plugins.socialsharing.share("content/text or link", "it's necessary indicate the subject even when is null", "it's  the same as the subject", "http://link");

Comment: Can you share both image and text at a time?